# Enable Mosaic Native Acceleration in GeoServer 2.17

Tags: raster, geoserver, wms, web-mapping, java

I am trying to optimise my server's GeoServer configuration for serving WMS. My server is running Ubuntu 19.10. I'm following the ['GeoServer on steroids' guide](https://www.slideshare.net/geosolutions/geoserver-on-steroids) which recommends enabling 'Mosaic Native Acceleration', amongst other things.

As I understand it, to do this I need to switch to native JAI, rather than the pure java version. I downloaded and installed the relevant files ([following this guide](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/production/java.html)) and also removed the pure java implementations from GeoServer's WEB-INF/libs directory as they were causing a conflict that prevented GeoServer from starting (also mentioned in the above guide).

My Geoserver status is as follows:

```
Data directory  /usr/share/geoserver/data_dir   
Locks   0   
Free locks
Connections     0   
Memory Usage    194 MB / 672 MB     
Free memory
JVM Version     Private Build: 1.8.0_252 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM)     
Java Rendering Engine   sun.java2d.pisces.PiscesRenderingEngine     
Available Fonts     GeoServer can access 314 different fonts. Full list of available fonts  
Native JAI  true    
Native JAI ImageIO  true    
JAI Maximum Memory  336 MB  
JAI Memory Usage    0 KB    
Free memory
JAI Memory Threshold    75%     
Number of JAI Tile Threads  7   
JAI Tile Thread Priority    5   
ThreadPoolExecutor Core Pool Size   5   
ThreadPoolExecutor Max Pool Size    10  
ThreadPoolExecutor Keep Alive Time (ms)     30000   
Update Sequence     578
```

I'd hoped this would allow me to check the 'Mosaic Native Acceleration' tick box on the 'Image Processing' setting page but — alas — the check box remains greyed out. How can I get this working?

Comment: That's a 9 year old presentation, I don't think we recommend native JAI any more.

Comment: oops! Is it still possible / desirable to enable Mosaic Native Acceleration? Why is it greyed out on my instance?

Comment: similarly, on my mosaic layers, I'm unable to uncheck 'Use JAI ImageRead' and cannot tick 'Multithreaded Granule Loading'.

Comment: just tried adding '-DallowNativeMosaic=true' to the JAVA_OPTS line in the init.d/geoserver script. Still no joy.